# Is this villager a nitwit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

Is the baby villager on the bed a nitwit?  I can't get a straight answer online.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. Nitwits always wear green robes.

He's just a regular baby... for now. When he grows up, he will either become a nitwit, or a productive member of his society :). No way to know until he grows.

The only way in which you could have a baby nitwit in a survival world is [by curing a baby zombie villager](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager?so=search#Nitwit):

> Zombie villagers can also be spawned as babies, so this is the only way to encounter baby nitwits in survival mode